# How to make a UIManagedDocument globally accessible to all ViewControllers in an app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, xcode4

Can anyone show me how to make a UIManagedDocument globally accessible?

Comment: I suggest looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8388048/sharing-data-string-with-a-singleton-between-views or almost any of its Related questions; this question isn't specific to `UIManagedDocument` as far as I can tell; you basically want guidance on sharing data between objects cleanly in iOS - the best terms to look for are probably "singleton" and "injection" and "shared model"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just pass mine around to my different view controllers like any other property.

```
newViewController.thatManagedDocument = self.thisManagedDocument;
```

No need to make it globally accessible.

Comment: @JJW not sure what you mean by that

Comment: This is my target:<br/> (AT)property (nonatomic, strong) UIManagedDocument *deliveryDatabase;
this is my source:<br/> (AT)property (nonatomic, strong) UIManagedDocument *deliveryDatabase;
and this is my attempt to do what you suggest:     ShiftAddTVC.deliveryDatabase = self.deliveryDatabase;
and I get the error:<br/> Property 'deliveryDatabase' not found on object of type 'ShiftAddTVC'.<br/>  Did I misunderstand your instructions?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding Objective-C. I'm going to assume ShiftAddTVC is a class...so classes do not have properties, only instances do. You should be calling it on an instance of that class...ShiftAddTVC *satvc = [ShiftAddTVC alloc] init]; ... satvc.deliveryDatabase = self.deliveryDatabase.

Comment: ShiftAddTVC is an instance of a CoreDataTableViewController.  It is in my Storyboard. So is AllShiftsTVC, the initial table view controller in the Storyboard.  So from AllShiftsTVC, in -(void)viewDidLoad I [super viewDidLoad]; and then ShiftAddTVC.deliveryDatabase = self.deliveryDatabase;

Comment: Oh Jeez, you're right, I don't understand things!  I apologize, I'm a Microsoft ASP.NET bigot trying to expand my horizons.  You are the Boss!